# xaml: How to change basic element properties using custom control through routed events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, custom-controls

I have created a custom control button in **Generic.xaml**  file and created a **click routed event** in **CustomControl.cs** `[C# file for custom control button]`,When I am defining a click events in **MainWidow.cs** `[C# file for implementing the custom library]` file so that its background property will change on button click.

Problem i am facing is that "On Button click"  its background property should change but it is not.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="my_ToolBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ravi="clr-namespace:my_ToolBox"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ravi:Button_Primary Text="Primary" x:Name="Primary_button"></ravi:Button_Primary>
</Grid></Window>
```

`MainWindow.cs`

```
namespace my_ToolBox
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Primary_button.onclick+=Primary_button_onclick;  
    }



    private static void Primary_button_onclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello robins");
        Button_Primary btn = new Button_Primary();
        btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.fromRgb(0,0,0));

    }
} 
}
```

`Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Button_Primary}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Button_Primary}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                    <Button Height="38" Width="86" Background="#428bca" BorderBrush="#428bca" BorderThickness="0"  Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" FontFamily="Segoe UI" x:Name="Primary_button">
                    </Button>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`CustomControl.cs`

```
namespace my_ToolBox
{

public class Button_Primary : Control
{
    private Button clickbutton;

    public static readonly RoutedEvent onclickevent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("onclick", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Button_Primary));

    static Button_Primary()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Button_Primary), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Button_Primary)));
    }


    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        clickbutton = GetTemplateChild("Primary_button") as Button;
        if(clickbutton!=null) clickbutton.Click+=clickbutton_Click;

    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler onclick
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(onclickevent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(onclickevent, value);
        }
    }



    private void clickbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(onclickevent));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Does the `Primary_button_onclick` handler get called at all?

Comment: @Sheridan yeah message box is showing but background property is still remaining same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found your problem... I'm sorry, but it's a *real* basic one too:

```
private static void Primary_button_onclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello robins");
    Button_Primary btn = new Button_Primary();
    btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.fromRgb(0,0,0));
}
```

Here, you create a new `Button_Primary` object and set *its* `Background` property *and not the `Background` of your UI element*:

```
Button_Primary btn = new Button_Primary();
btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.fromRgb(0,0,0));
```

All you need to do is to access your *actual* `Button_Primary` object from the UI... how do you do that? Well, you can find the full story from the [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, but the gist of it is this: You need an instance of a control that *has the relevant `ControlTemplate` applied to it* and then you can simply use the [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access the `Button`.